# Django viewset action does not see request's added data in the middleware

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, middleware

I have a very strange problem. I have written a middleware which patches a request object with custom property. And it works perfectly in the whole project except 1 action. Here they are:
**Middleware**:

```
class AssignSelectedProfileMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        headers = request.META

        if not request.user.is_anonymous:
            if headers.get(HEADER_PROFILE):
                profile = Profile.objects.filter(pk=headers.get(HEADER_PROFILE),
                                                 archived=False,
                                                 user=request.user).first()
            else:
                profile = Profile.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
            if not profile:
                raise MyProfileAuthorizationError("You are not allowed to use this profile.")
            setattr(request, "user", request.user._wrapped)
            setattr(request.user, "profile", profile)
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response
```

**Action**:

```
@action(
        methods=['get', 'patch'],
        detail=False,
        permission_classes=(IsAuthenticated,),
        serializer_class=SafeProfileSerializer,
    )
    def me(self, request):
        return Response(self.get_serializer(self.request.user.profile).data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

When I make a response - I see that request is patched successfully in the middleware, Profile object exists, but when I debug request in the view - `self.request.user.profile` throws `AttributeError: 'User' object has no attribute 'profile'`. Note - another actions in the save viewset work perfectly and `user.profile` exists. Why this happens?

**EDIT 1:** Prints in middleware and action:

```
Middleware: {'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7f9e04b04908>, 'id': 1, 'password': 'pbkdf2_sha256$120000$Wxoqm8SATZWk$wVM5uRknaCig+nU7tlY4iQnkwgvJDavdHQHpKBRIstw=', 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 15, 9, 11, 36, 296195), 'is_superuser': False, 'username': 'username0', 'first_name': 'Benjamin', 'last_name': 'Allen', 'email': 'williamsdaniel@hotmail.com', 'is_staff': False, 'is_active': True, 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 15, 9, 11, 35, 808270), 'profile': <Profile: Benjamin Allen, administrator: False>}

View:  {'_state': <django.db.models.base.ModelState object at 0x7f9e04b10358>, 'id': 1, 'password': 'pbkdf2_sha256$120000$Wxoqm8SATZWk$wVM5uRknaCig+nU7tlY4iQnkwgvJDavdHQHpKBRIstw=', 'last_login': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 15, 9, 11, 36, 296195), 'is_superuser': False, 'username': 'username0', 'first_name': 'Benjamin', 'last_name': 'Allen', 'email': 'williamsdaniel@hotmail.com', 'is_staff': False, 'is_active': True, 'date_joined': datetime.datetime(2019, 5, 15, 9, 11, 35, 808270)}
```

**EDIT 2:**
If I add in middleware smth like this:

```
if request.path_info == '/api/users/me/':
    setattr(request, "me_action_profile", profile)
```

And call it in the action like this:

```
return Response(self.get_serializer(self.request.me_action_profile).data, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

It works. But why can't I patch a `user` object in this particular case?

Comment: does the middleware patch succeed to ***any other custom viewset actions***?

Comment: @JPG, yes, for example I have a `change_email` action in the same viewset - and I can access an `user.profile` object

Comment: Does the request to the **`me`** action going through **`AssignSelectedProfileMiddleware`** middleware? (we can check that using simple `print()` function)

Comment: @JPG yes, and print shows that during that request in the middleware `request.user.profile` exists and when it gets to the view - `profile` object disappears. May be that somehow connected with object *lazyness*?